# Do we need infinitely many objects to make one have kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, thought-experiment

We have one ball at rest. How can we give it energy to make it move? One way is by striking it with another moving ball, for which we need another ball with energy. Then how can we make the other ball to have kinetic energy? We need one more ball and etc..

Considering this how can our world with moving objects exist? Or did the balls have energies from the beginning?

Comment: I'm sure there will be good answers here, but you may want to also see this question at the Philosophy Stack Exchange: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/is-infinite-regress-of-causation-possible-is-infinite-regress-of-causation-nece

Comment: Have you considered that the universe may have started with some energy? Maybe then you're asking a question about how the Big Bang happened. There are ways around the apparent paradox. You might also like to read about the ubiquitous zero-point energy of quantum mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy

Comment: My impression from your question is that English is not your native language.  I would suggest using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) if this is the case.

Comment: Did the universe have balls in the beginning?

Comment: @BGreen, do You have a specific answer?

Comment: @RodneyDunning, too many letters, plus in english, I'm lazy to read

Comment: @Artur If you want people to help you with your questions, you must put in the effort of reading their answers and the resources they point to.